# Change UIButton state programmatically

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I am trying to change a UIButton's state programmatically, so that when i tap it, the background stays blue. I can change the enabled property and that works, but changing selected or highlighted doesnt affect the state.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always keep track of your own state independently of the button with an ivar and then change the background of the button to suit the state.

Comment: So the selected and highlighted properties are useless?